# Why didn't PEP 3107 (or 484) include syntax for annotating global/local variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis, type-hinting, static-typing

PEP 3107 describes syntax for adding annotations to Python function parmeters and return values. PEP 484 gives them a meaning.

Why didn't they include syntax for annotating global and local variables? I seems to me that allowing following forms of variable declaration wouldn't cause conflicts with existing Python syntax, and it would be in line with function parameter syntax:

```
x: int
x: int = 3
```

Seems that annotating variables is considered important: Mypy resorts to special comments for annotating variables: http://mypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/type_inference_and_annotations.html#explicit-types-for-variables

Comment: Speculation as to why something was decided should be looked for on the Python mailinglists where those PEPs where discussed, or you can ask the authors of the PEP. PEP 484 works within the constraints of PEP 3107, which probably never considered variable assignments.

Comment: Note that name binding is.. tricky and goes beyond just assignment (think `for` loops or `with ... as ...` statements). Most static tools analyse what the *right-hand side expression* produces to assign a type to a name, at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Python 3.6 has support for variable annotations: [PEP 526](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#variable-annotations)